# How add js and css on home page (slider) to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, js-css

In Magento 1 I include js and css like this:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/masterslider.min.js</script></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/masterslider.css</stylesheet></action>
```

But in Magento 2 this not works.

How correct add **masterslider.min.js** and **masterslider.css** to Magento 2 (slider for home page)?
This html insert to home page (admin-panel):

```
<div class="master-slider ms-skin-default" id="masterslider">

    <div class="ms-slide" data-delay="10">

        <img src="media/blank.gif" data-src="media/001.jpg" alt="Test slide"/>     

    </div>

</div>

<script>
    jQuery(function($){
    var slider = new MasterSlider();
    slider.setup('masterslider' , {
        width:1200,
        height:600,
        space:0,
        autoplay:true,
        loop:true,
        speed:8,
        view:"fade"
    });
    slider.control('arrows');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: For a long time I am looking for a solution. Has anyone had experience of connecting the slider to the home page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct way!

1. Path: `app/design/frontend/My-vendor/my-name-theme/web`
2. Add `masterslider.min.js` to `app/design/frontend/My-vendor/my-name-theme/web/js`
3. Create `requirejs-config.js` to `app/design/frontend/My-vendor/my-name-theme`

   `var config = {
       paths: {
           masterslider:        'js/masterslider.min',
       },
       shim: {
           masterslider: {
               deps: ['jquery']
           }
       }
   };`
4. Add masterslider.css to `app/design/frontend/My-vendor/my-name-theme/web/css/source`
5. Use or create file `_extend.less` to `app/design/frontend/My-vendor/my-name-theme/web/css/source` Write in `_extend.less` this in the last row:
   `@import 'masterslider.css';`
6. `cd /var/www/domain/html
   rm -rf pub/static/*
   rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
   php /var/www/domain/html/bin/magento cache:clean
   php /var/www/domain/html/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US ru_RU
   php /var/www/domain/html/bin/magento cache:clean`
7. Call slider in content home page or in file phtml like this:

```
<script>

    require([
        'jquery',
        'masterslider'
    ], function($) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#masterslider').show().masterslider({
            /* code slider */
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: from which place i need to copy masterslider.min.js or it is already available in magento 2 default themes

Answer (score 5):

Add css and js from your frontend layout file

You need to add below code in **app/code/Vendor/Modulename/frontend/layout/routname_controllername_action.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Modulename::js/your-js.js"/>
        <css src="Vendor_Modulename::css/your-css.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

Your js and css path will be

**app/code/Vendor/Modulename/frontend/web/css/your-css.css**
**app/code/Vendor/Modulename/frontend/web/js/your-js.js**

Comment: The code I need to write to a file app/code/Vendor/Modulename/frontend/requirejs-config.js?

Comment: Updated answer with file path please check it

Comment: Do I make the command setup:upgrade after?

Comment: No you do not need that command if cache enable the run `php bin/magento cache:flush` and after that `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: I try, but not works on home page...

Comment: For homepage you need to create cms_index_index.xml file

Comment: But I insert slide code to home page. Perhaps the answer is not coming to my problem.

Comment: You have added slide code there so you also need to add css and js on homepage using cms_index_index.xml

Comment: Thank you! I make all steps, but this not works. You try add slider to home page? In Magento 1 I include 2 files: js and css, and in admin panel home page write slide code (not join js and css).

Comment: confirm your js and css call on home page or not otherwise update question with code

Comment: Maybe you know how make correct slider when you have 2 files: slider.js and css? The goal - to have a working slider on the home page, having two js css file.

Comment: add this code `<head>
        <script src="Vendor_Modulename::js/your-js.js"/>
        <css src="Vendor_Modulename::css/your-css.css"/>
    </head>`  in cms page-> Design->  Layout Update XM

Comment: I would recommend adding the JS via require JS instead of the XML

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in you custom theme `app\design\frontend\<vendor>\<theme>\Magento_Theme\layout\cms_index_index.xml\` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
       <script src="js/your-js.js"/>
       <css src="css/your-css.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>              
    </body>
</page>
```

And you can add this file in `app\design\frontend\<vendor>\<theme>\web\css` and `app\design\frontend\<vendor>\<theme>\web\js` respected folder.

Comment: I have luma theme.

Comment: I would never recommend to change the code inside a core module as this will cause issues with any magento updates in future. so Just create new custom theme check this doc to create custom theme [How to create theme?](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html).