# Magento 2 has default slider js?

Tags: javascript, magento2.4, banner-slider

Magento 2 provide default Slider js rather than use third party slider js ? Because I do want to increase js size of Magento 2 Store. I tried to search,but I could not find any slider js.

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151309/how-add-js-and-css-on-home-page-slider-to-magento-2

Comment: @LitExtensionMagentoMigration I do not want to add new js. Your link promates to add new  slider js  which I do not want. Read my question again

Comment: You cannot find slider js in Magento. Also, my advice is that you shouldn't fix anything related to Magento's default features as it is a chain linking the functions together, if you edit it will break the flow of its activity

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question for Magento 2.4.6.

Pagebuilder use Slick slider, so, I think it's default for Magento 2.4

https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, Magento 2.4.1 or higher version includes Page Builder, which provides the option to add a banner slider. This slider functionality uses the Slick slider, indicating that Magento utilizes the Slick slider for this purpose.**

> **Below is a sample HTML code demonstrating how to use the default Slick slider without any additional third-party slider JavaScript.**

```
<div data-content-type="row" data-appearance="contained" data-element="main">
   <div data-enable-parallax="0" data-parallax-speed="0.5" data-background-images="{}" data-background-type="image" data-video-loop="true" data-video-play-only-visible="true" data-video-lazy-load="true" data-video-fallback-src="" data-element="inner" >
      <div class="pagebuilder-slider" data-content-type="slider" data-appearance="default" data-autoplay="true" data-autoplay-speed="4000" data-fade="true" data-infinite-loop="true" data-show-arrows="true" data-show-dots="true" data-element="main">
         <div data-content-type="slide" data-slide-name="" data-appearance="poster" data-show-button="never" data-show-overlay="never" data-element="main">
            <div data-element="empty_link">
               <div class="pagebuilder-slide-wrapper">
                  <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/purple-pi.png" />
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div data-content-type="slide" data-slide-name="" data-appearance="poster" data-show-button="never" data-show-overlay="never" data-element="main">
            <div data-element="empty_link">
               <div class="pagebuilder-slide-wrapper">
                     <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/spunky-sam-green.png" />
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div data-content-type="slide" data-slide-name="" data-appearance="poster" data-show-button="never" data-show-overlay="never" data-element="main">
            <div data-element="empty_link">
               <div class="pagebuilder-slide-wrapper">
                     <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/purple-pi-teal.png" />
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

> **You can review the file path below for more information about the slider:**

```
vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type/slider.xml
```

Comment: thank you very much for information, page builder starts from 2.4.1 version so please correct it